# Android appium test xpath changes for the same controls for different mobile devices with different screen size as well as different android version.

Tags: java, eclipse, automated-tests, appium-android, aws-device-farm

Android appium test xpath of same controls changes for different mobile devices with different screen size as well as different android version. Thus iam not able to run the test scripts in amazon device farm for multiple mobile devices.Also its  not possible to assign unique id for all elements during devolopment.Most elements being generated dynamically.What is a possible solution to this?

Comment: Please provide some example code and HTML, to check if there is some other possibilities

Comment: Could you provide the page source and how that changes?

Comment: Any update here?